# Proof with binomial coefficients and induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, binomial-coefficients

I am stuck and unable to prove the following expression with induction

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2 n}{2 k}= 2^{2n-1} $$

where $n>0$. One has to show that the equality below is satisfied:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{2n+2}{2k} = 2^{2n+1}. $$

I have tried to show with binomial identities and index moving that one can come from $\binom{2n+2}{2k}$ to $\binom{2n}{2k}$.
Unfortunately I cannot move on with this.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think this is easier without the use of induction - **must** you use induction?

Comment: You can't prove it because it is **not** true for $n=0$. I suggest trying to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{2k} = 2^{n-1}$ for $n>0$.

Comment: @Somos provided ${n \in \mathbb{N}}$, which is what I would've assumed anyway - then surely this is fine?

Comment: Without explicit induction. Let $S$ be the sum in question and $f(x)=(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n$. Then $f(1)=2S$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose yes I have to.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik did not find something similer enough, thanks for the edit btw

Comment: @Somos forgot to note it. it has to be true from n >=1

Answer (score 0):

How $\binom{m}{p}=\binom{m-1}{p-1}+\binom{m-1}{p}$, if $m=2n$ and $p=2k$, then:

$$\binom{2n+2}{2k}=\binom{2n}{2k-2}+2\cdot\binom{2n}{2k-1}+\binom{2n}{2k}$$
Therefore

\begin{eqnarray*}{}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n+2}{2k}&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n}{2k-2}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n}{2k}\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{2n}{2k-2}+\binom{2n}{-2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k-1}+2\binom{2n}{-1}+2\binom{2n}{2n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}+\binom{2n}{2n+2}\end{eqnarray*}

Take $\binom{m}{p}=0$, if $p<0$ or $p>m$, then:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n+2}{2k}
=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{2n}{2k-2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}$$

How
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k-1}$$
And
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{2n}{2k-2}$$
Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n+2}{2k}
=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{2n}{2k-2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}=4\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}=2^2\cdot2^{2n-1}=2^{2n+1}$$

Comment: the transformation in the first line with the application of the identity is unclear, could you write it more elaborately?

Comment: @Ozk applied the identitie two times: $$\binom{2n+2}{2k}=\binom{2n+1}{2k-1}+\binom{2n+1}{2k}=\binom{2n}{2k-2}+\binom{2n}{2k-1}+\binom{2n}{2k-1}+\binom{2n}{2k}=\binom{2n}{2k-2}+2\binom{2n}{2k-1}+\binom{2n}{2k}$$